# How to add docstrings to a module that I can't write to

Tags: python, docstring

I have a module to which additional functions are programmatically getting written to.
I.e.:

```
def fun1():   # function written on 27.02.13
    ...

def fun2():   # function written on 28.02.13
    ...
```

I would like to add [docstrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring#Python) to the module itself and these functions during runtime without modifying the file.

Is this possible to do via another script?

Comment: I reworded the question. I think it is now valid to the stackoverflow community rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, just add a `__doc__` attribute to the module:

```
import foo

foo.__doc__ = '''My docstring for this module'''
```

Comment: wow that was quick!
many many thanks, i knew it would be something obvious